# What's the difference between 蓓 (bèi) and 萌 (méng), both nouns that mean "bud"?

Tags: characters, difference

> [蓓](http://youdao.com/w/%E8%93%93) n. bud (part of [蓓蕾](http://youdao.com/w/%E8%93%93%E8%95%BE) (bèilěi))
>   [萌](http://youdao.com/w/eng/%E8%90%8C) n. bud; vt. sprout, germinate (part of [萌芽](http://youdao.com/w/%E8%90%8C%E8%8A%BD) (méngyá))

I asked a student (who happens to have the name 萌) if 蓓 and 萌 are the same, but she said they're different.  I'm not sure why though.

My guess from the above is that 蓓 is bud that will turn into a flower, whereas 萌 is more general, and refers to anything that sprouts.

**Question**: What's the difference between 蓓 and 萌?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally:

- [萌](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E8%90%8C) is a **verb** meaning to *bud*.
- [蓓](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E8%93%93) is a **noun** meaning *bud*.

---

蓓 is usually just a compound character only found in the word 蓓蕾.